mat-toolbar is not a known element [Angular 18]
I know there are very similar problems related to import and modules but I could not reproduce the solutions proposed and I am stuck for a few days by now so I am humbly asking for help to be able to solve that blocking that prevent me to follow through the book "Pro Angular 16".
I am using VoidLinux with node v18.19.1, pnpm 9.6 (I did add cli: { "packageManager": "pnpm" } in angular.json), @angular/cli 18.1.2
Running pnpm ng serve -o returns the following errors that occur sequentially:
[ERROR] NG8001: 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element
[ERROR] NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element
[ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'matBadge' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-icon'

I did try to add schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SHEMAS], or schemas: [NO_ERROR_SCHEMAS], just below the decorator @NgModule({ in app.module.ts with the matching import to the first line (e.g. import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'; but to no avail.
Here is my app.module.ts:
// import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      FormsModule,
      MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatBadgeModule,
      MatTableModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatSlideToggleModule, 
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }

app.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoList } from "./todoList";
import { TodoItem } from "./todoItem";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root', // CSS selector that matches HTML tag to which the component will be applied
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'todo';
  private list = new TodoList('Aurèle', [
    new TodoItem("Finish the UBC website", true),
    new TodoItem('Write some unit tests'),
    new TodoItem('Learn Angular'),
    new TodoItem('Write a word document for the jury'),
    new TodoItem('Buy INCOSE book related to SysML v2', true),
  ]);

  get username(): string {
    return this.list.user;
  }

  get itemCount(): number {
    return this.list.items.filter(item => !item.complete).length;
  }
}

app.component.html:
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z3">
   <span>{{ username }}'s to do list</span>
   <mat-icon matBadge="{{ itemCount }}" matBadgeColor="accent">
      checklist
   </mat-icon>
</mat-toolbar>

The imports are actually in the module and not in the component itself. Besides, the component is not marked as standadlone so I understand not why the properties related to Angular Material package are not found, because they do exist in node_modules/@angular/material subdirectory!
@EDIT
I altered main.ts to look like this:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

Now the error reported by Angular is this:
[vite] Internal server error: NG0907: The _AppComponent component is not marked as standalone, but Angular expects to have a standalone component here. Please make sure the _AppComponent component has the `standalone: true` flag in the decorator.

But what if I add standalone: true; into app.component.ts? It is not a standalone but a module declared into app.module.ts so I understand not the situation.
As asserted in the docs' links kindly provided by Naren Murali, I will try to stick to standalone components mechanism from now on, as it is the recommanded way to go.

does your main.ts look like this? `import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => console.error(err));
`

It was not. Your 2 imports and last statement were missing.
Thank you, I eddited the main message accordingly to reflect the current situation.

Please alter main.ts to look like this. Main.ts is the entry point for an Angular application, so it must be bootstrapped properly by either a component or module.
You are mixing standalone and modular, you must choose between either.
Importing and using components
NgModules
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

Since your code is predominately about modular method, I am suggesting the above code, but it can also be implemented with standalone flow.

As said in the doc in the link you provided, standalone components are the current way to proceed whereas NgModules mechanisms are the old one.
I will try to stick to the former method when learning through "Pro Angular 16" book, hoping that I will be able to overcome the hassle that could occur when perusing the pages.
Your suggested solution did work but raised some error, not the in browser but in VS Code, throwing messages like 'The module is marked as a standalone component'.
Many thanks for your insight! I could not upvote your answer as my reputation is below 15.

@AurélienPlazzotta create a new project you will notice app component is standalone, inside that decorator add an imports array and add the imports this will solve your issue
